# Which preposition goes better for computer system?

Tags: prepositions

When we say something in specified operating system, which preposition should I use? 
e.g.

> I play games {in/on/under} Windows.

Comment: Related at EL&U: *[“Run on an OS” vs. “run under an OS”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/88216)* and *[“On Mac OS X” vs. “in Mac OS X”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56468/)*, and more generally *[Using “on” vs. “in”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59843/)*

Answer (score 2):

Programs run ON operating systems, but I think few people would say that they play a game on *Windows*, they would say they play a game on a *computer* running Windows.

Comment: or, I play the games designed for Windows/Android/Mac platform

Answer (score 1):

I play games ON Windows.This is because any application runs on top of the Operating System.

If you say "I play games IN Windows", it could means games available as a part of the Operating System, present inside the OS. If you want to mean that, then I think you can say "IN Windows".

Answer (score 0):

The answer might vary by country (Indian English, British English, American English).  In the US, we would say "...games that run under Windows".

See [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=that%20run%20under%20Windows%2Cthat%20run%20on%20Windows%2Cthat%20run%20in%20Windows&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthat%20run%20under%20Windows%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthat%20run%20on%20Windows%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthat%20run%20in%20Windows%3B%2Cc0).