# Should I use "on" or "in" or "over" or "at" or "within" or other preposition in the expresion "I installed it on Windows"?

Tags: prepositions

Many times I use this expresion and I would like to know which is the correct way to say this. I do not know what preposition I should use in this expresions:

- I installed it **on** Windows
- Is that running **in** Windows?
- Is it loaded **over** Windows?
- How to get used to Chrome **within** Windows?

Can I use all of them? Is there a general rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no general rule but only **"on"** and **"in"** are possible.

"**within**" and "**over**" can't be used with OS or software.

- How to install fonts **in** Windows Vista.
- How to install Microsoft Office 2016 **on** Windows XP.

Sources:

- [Which preposition goes better for computer system?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/63365/which-preposition-goes-better-for-computer-system)
- [Install on, install in, install to](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103542/install-on-install-in-install-to)